# I need to migrate from On-premises database PostgreSQL of version 9 to Azure SQL

Tags: postgresql, azure-sql-database

I need to migrate on premises DB PostgreSQL ver 9.* to Azure SQL , without using third party tool. How can I achieve it..?

Comment: Dump then import? (Note that "9.*" covers **7** major versions - not a very precise version information)

Comment: Could you please confirm you want to migrate to Azure SQL Database or Azure SQL for Postgresql?

Comment: I would like to migrate to Azure SQL Database

Comment: And it is having "EnterpriseDB Postgres Advanced server 9.4.4.9"